# Bootstrap 4 having an issue setting md breakpoints for columns and wrapping to incorrect row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm sure all sorts of variations of this have been asked, but I've been unable to find a solution for this layout.  Basic markup is this (I removed a lot of the padding and margin classes for clarity)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row border-bottom">
    <div class="col d-none d-md-block" style="-ms-flex: 0 0 125px;flex: 0 0 125px;">
       [logo image]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 d-md-block align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <h5> [school name]</h5>
      <p class="d-inline"> [city state]</p>

      <div class="row d-none d-sm-flex">
        <div class="col">Website</div>
        <div class="col">Setting</div>
        <div class="col">Size</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2 align-items-center" style="border:1px solid plum">
     <a class="btn btn-sm btn-collegeList align-items-center justify-content-center px-1 px-md-2"> profile</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This works as expected for full size displays and smaller displays, but in the medium sizes that 3rd column (containing the button) wraps around under the fixed-width logo column:
[image: medium image with bad wrap]

I'd like that to stay to the right like it is in the large, or at least centered under the content as it is in the small.[image: large]

and the small

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your layout to be same on the small devices you can use `.col-sm-*` instead of using `.col-md-*`
Medium screen will be `≥768px` and small will be `≥576px`
It depends up to you.

I am putting both the solution so that you can keep it as you want it to be on large devices or you can stack it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row border-bottom">
    <div class="col-sm-2 d-none d-md-block" style="-ms-flex: 0 0 125px;flex: 0 0 125px;">
       [logo image]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 d-md-block align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <h5> [school name]</h5>
      <p class="d-inline"> [city state]</p>

      <div class="row d-none d-sm-flex">
        <div class="col">Website</div>
        <div class="col">Setting</div>
        <div class="col">Size</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 align-items-center" style="border:1px solid plum">
     <a class="btn btn-sm btn-collegeList align-items-center justify-content-center px-1 px-md-2"> profile</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row border-bottom">
    <div class="col-sm-2 d-none d-md-block" style="-ms-flex: 0 0 125px;flex: 0 0 125px;">
       [logo image]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 d-md-block align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <h5> [school name]</h5>
      <p class="d-inline"> [city state]</p>

      <div class="row d-none d-sm-flex">
        <div class="col">Website</div>
        <div class="col">Setting</div>
        <div class="col">Size</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 align-items-center" style="border:1px solid plum">
     <a class="btn btn-sm btn-collegeList align-items-center justify-content-center px-1 px-md-2"> profile</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the reference of [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)